# Rails & Devise: How to authenticate specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise for the first time with rails, and I'm having trouble with one thing: 
I used the provided `authenticate_user!` method in my user's controller to restrict access to pages like so:
`before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :show, :update, :create, :destroy]`

But this allows any signed in user to access any other users `:edit` action, which I want to restrict to only that user. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your edit method, you need to do a check to see if the user owns the record:

```
def edit
   @record = Record.find(params[:id])
   if @record.user == current_user
      @record.update_attributes(params[:record])
   else
      redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this. I get the following error:
`uninitialized constant UsersController::Record`
Also I find it really surprising that a well developed authentication method like this doesn't have direct support for something like this.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is what I did:
`private
   def verify_ownership
     @record = Record.find(params[:id])
     if @record.user == current_user
        return true
      else
        return false
    end`

and then I use a `before_filter` at the top of my controller

Comment: replace `Record` with whatever your actual model name is. I am also assuming that your model has a `user_id` column. You can use CanCan or Declarative Authentication with this. Or just use if-then-else statements to ensure proper permissions. Devise handles authentications, not roles.

Comment: I tried replacing `Record` with `User`, and then I check if `@record == current_user`, but for some reason this still allows any user to edit any other user's records

Comment: Forget what I said about a `before_filter`, you need to redirect instead of returning true/false. Take the code out and put it in the actual method.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Authorization such as CanCan. Or alternatively create a new method like so:

```
# Create an admin boolean column for your user table.

def authenticate_admin!
  authenticate_user! and current_user.admin?
end
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't need administrator users who can edit any user's records. I just need to restrict users to be able to modify only their own records.

Comment: He did misunderstand it a little but you should still look into using CanCan.  You're looking for Authorization and CanCan does it wonderfully.